# List the months between two dates asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I had the below code to list the last day of every month between two dates 
but my problem is I did not get the last day from the months.

for example : `Date1: 31/10/2017 Date2: 31/3/2018`

my Result :

```
31-10-2017
30-11-2017
30-12-2017
30-1-2017
28-2-2018
28-3-2018
```

it should be

```
31-10-2017
30-11-2017
31-12-2017
31-1-2017
28-2-2018
31-3-2018
```

code:

```
Dim startDay As Date = StartDate.SelectedDate
Dim endDay As Date = EndDate.SelectedDate
Dim dayCtr As Date
dayCtr = startDay
Do While (dayCtr <= endDay)
     ' MsgBox(dayCtr.Date.Day & "-" & dayCtr.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString())
      ListBox1.Items.Add(dayCtr.Date.Day & "-" & dayCtr.Date.Month.ToString() & "-" & dayCtr.Date.Year.ToString())
      dayCtr = dayCtr.AddMonths(1)
Loop
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddMonth(1) adds 1 to the month component of the date (and kindly wraps around to the next year so you don't have to do that) but the rest is up to you.

```
Private Function GetLastDayOfMonth(currentDate As Date) As Date
    Dim result As Date
    'Jump one Month ahead 
    result = currentDate.AddMonths(1)
    'Go to first day of that Month
    result = New Date(result.Year, result.Month, 1)
    'Go one day back
    result = result.AddDays(-1)
    Return result

End Function
```

Use this function in your code like so:

```
Dim startDay As Date = StartDate.SelectedDate
Dim endDay As Date = EndDate.SelectedDate
Dim dayCtr As Date
dayCtr = startDay
Do While (dayCtr <= endDay)

    ' MsgBox(dayCtr.Date.Day & "-" & dayCtr.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString())
    Dim lastDay As Date = GetLastDayOfMonth(dayCtr)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(lastDay.Date.Day & "-" & lastDay.Date.Month.ToString() & "-" & lastDay.Date.Year.ToString())
    dayCtr = dayCtr.AddMonths(1)
Loop
```

and you should be fine. .NET helps you A LOT with handling dates but a little elbow grease is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

Little bid different approach by using `Date.DaysInMonth` method without extra operations

```
Private Iterator Function GetLastDatesFrom(startDate As Date, 
                                           endDate As Date) As IEnumerable(Of Date)
    Dim temp = startDate
    Do While (temp <= endDate)
        Dim lastDay = Date.DaysInMonth(temp.Year, temp.Month)
        Yield New Date(temp.Year, temp.Month, lastDay)

        temp = temp.AddMonths(1)
    Loop
End Function
```

Then

```
Dim startDay As Date = StartDate.SelectedDate
Dim endDay As Date = EndDate.SelectedDate

Dim dates = GetLastDatesFromRange(startDay, endDay).ToList()
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(dates)
```

Comment: I know about `DaysInMonth` and should have mentioned it, but I thought it was good to display the workings of adding and subtracting days. :)